# Installing a package using apt get to serverless node.js app

Tags: node.js, serverless, apt, vercel

I want to install packages using **apt get** on **vercel serverless node.js**.
how can i do it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Former Vercel engineer here.
I'm afraid it's not possible. Serverless functions are built in isolated containers and packaged for AWS Lambda.
If you need to use a specific package, you should check if it's available via npm (a lot of tools are, like for example Puppeteer). Otherwise it's not possible.