# Puppeteer issue during Vercel deployment : Error: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium, vercel

I have created a REST API with express and I first need to scrap data with puppeteer during the build process. However vercel fails to scrap data with puppeteer during deployment.

I get this issue : Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

First, I have checked this page :
[Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer) and [How to solve Puppeteer: failed to launch the browser process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795309/how-to-solve-puppeteer-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process)

All answers to my issue say to install lib using `sudo apt-get install`, but I also read this question :
[Installing a package using apt get to serverless node.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824032/installing-a-package-using-apt-get-to-serverless-node-js-app)

That say we can only download packages with npm during vercel deployment.

So it seems impossible to do what I want (I don't want to have my scrapped data in my github repo, I want to scrap them during build process.)

I also tried this approach : https://github.com/michaelkitas/Puppeteer-Vercel (with `chrome-aws-lambda` and `puppeteer-core` but it still doesn't work, I have the same issue.)

my build cmd : `node scrap.js && node index.js`

my code to scrap :

```
const fs = require("fs");
onst fs = require("fs");

let chrome = {};
let puppeteer;

if (process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION) {
  chrome = require("chrome-aws-lambda");
  puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
} else {
  puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
}

const writeIconFile = (name, content) => {
  fs.appendFile(name, content, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
};

const scrap = async () => {
  let options = {};

  if (process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION) {
    options = {
      args: [...chrome.args, "--hide-scrollbars", "--disable-web-security"],
      defaultViewport: chrome.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chrome.executablePath,
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    };
  }

  let data;
  try {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
    data = await page.title();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    data = null;
  }
  return data;
};

scrap().then((data) => {
  writeIconFile("data.txt", data);
});
```